# Using Terraform as an API

Tags: terraform

I would like to use Terraform programmatically like an API/function calls to create and teardown infrastructure in multiple specific steps. e.g reserve a couple of eips, add an instance to a region and assign one of the IPs all in separate steps. Terraform will currently run locally and not on a server.

I would like to know if there is a recommended way/best practices for creating the configuration to support this? So far it seems that my options are:

1. Properly define input/output, heavily rely on resource separation, modules, the count parameter and interpolation.
2. Generate the configuration files as JSON which appears to be less common

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Terraform directly, I would recommend a 3rd party build/deploy tool such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo), [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/), etc. to manage the release of your infrastructure managed by Terraform. Reason being is that you should treat your Terraform code in the exact same manner as you would application code (i.e. have a proper build/release pipeline). As an added bonus, these tools come integrated with a standard api that can be used to execute your build and deploy processes.

If you choose not to create a build/deploy pipeline, your other options are to use a tool such as [RunDeck](https://www.rundeck.com/what-is-rundeck) which allows you to execute arbitrary commands on a server. It also has the added bonus of having a excellent privilege control system to only allow specified users to execute commands. Your other option could be to upgrade from the Open Source version of Terraform to the [Pro/Premium](https://www.hashicorp.com/products/terraform) version. This version includes an integrated GUI and extensive [API](https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/api/index.html).

As for best practices for using an API to automate creation/teardown of your infrastructure with Terraform, the best practices are the same regardless of what tools you are using. You mentioned some good practices such as clearly defining input/output and creating a separation of concerns which are excellent practices! Some others I can recommend are:

1. Create all of your infrastructure code with [idempotency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) in mind.
2. Use modules to separate the common shared portions of your code. This reduces the number of places that you will have to update code and therefore the number of points of error when pushing an update.
3. Write your code with scalability in mind from the beginning. It is much simpler to start with this than to adjust later on when it is too late.

Comment: Thanks Preston. My use case is fairly simple so a build/deploy pipeline may be overkill but perhaps it can be of some benefit and I will look into it more. In general I think that this is one level above what I am currently researching . This is more how to run Terraform once it is already set up to run. I am currently looking into how to set it up so that it can be configured and interfaced with programmatically. e.g. The ability to create / destroy in separate steps with various input. The ability to query results (output).

Comment: @user1247196 It is unclear to me where you are starting with Terraform. Do have Terraform installed locally or on a server?
 Have you created a Terraform config file? Maybe that is something you can clarify in the question.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am running locally. My question is regarding the configuration files. Do I set up the configuration to support all the input/output I need and use modules, templates and resource separation or generate the configuration myself outside of terraform first. As of know I think that the first approach will work well enough

Comment: How would you setup the configuration yourself outside of Terraform?

Comment: I was considering the option of programmatically generating the configuration as JSON

Comment: @user1247196 if you are EVER going to modify the contents of your configuration, use the terraform file. If you want to programatically create the JSON file and store that you can, but keep in mind, if you want to edit that,you will have to either modify your program, or modify the JSON file by hand (which will be incredibly painful). If it were me, I would 100% use the .tf format vs the .tf.json file because the .tf files are incredibly easy to read and modify compared to the .tf.json fromat.

Comment: You could look into Geoengineer. It's a Ruby DSL for Terraform. It doesn't support all resources, but it's worth a look. https://github.com/coinbase/geoengineer